# Multi Purpose Epson WF-3640 Error Code:Ox69

Tags: printer

Printer was working fine.Last week I allowed entering a critical up date to printer but I do not remember what it was. Next time I went to print something I got the following on the printer display window: Printer error. Turn the power off and on again. For details, see your documentation or visit Epson.com. Error CodeOx69. I have turned off and back on several times and got the same error.  My cd manual does not say anything about this error code as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the cartridges? Make sure the cartridges are placed properly.
 After that, restart the printer.